# How to get Django and React to work together?

Tags: reactjs, django

I have used Webpack and Babel with Django REST Framework but I had a lot of issues. I am also interested in using Vite but I got lost in the [installation guide](https://github.com/MrBin99/django-vite).

I'm looking to create a simple Django API backend and React frontend (fetching data with Axios).

What's the best way to integrate React and Django?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[here you can find how to implemente it](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JD-age0BPVo&list=PLzMcBGfZo4-kCLWnGmK0jUBmGLaJxvi4j)